# Mapping from Entity Type to DTO in API application

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, mapping, automapper

I have an WebAPI application and I am having to map from entity objects to DTO to cater for what the API response should look like. For this mapping between Entity type and DTO I am using `AutoMapper` like below:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerEntity, CustomerDTO>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.Age, opts => opts.Ignore())
.ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.CustomerName));
```

Then with a single line from one of the action I get to return required JSON format with appropriate property names:

```
public CustomerDTO GetCustomer(int Id)
{
   return Mapper.Map<CustomerEntity, CustomerDTO>(db.Customer.Find(id));
}
```

But because of this I am having to create many types (DTO) and I would prefer to just get me an `anonymous` or `dynamic` result since it is going to be returned as JSON anyway and I am not using those types for anything else.

I can also do a projection like below:

```
public CustomerDTO GetCustomer(int Id)
{
   var customer = db.Customer.Find(id));
   return new CustomerDTO{ Name = customer.CustomerName, OtherProperty = "others" };
}
```

But then I would have to manually repeat the code and I will also miss out on AutoMapper's mapping configuration features like above.

In essence what would be really helpful is something like below:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerEntity, dynamic>()
.ForMember("Age", opts => opts.Ignore())
.ForMember("Name", opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.CustomerName));
```

But that is not possible. This is more of a conceptual question rather than a concrete one so please help me understand *how I can prevent creating DTOs in an API application to cater for difference between response structure (JSON) and entity objects* assuming that is even an option. Any other suggestion is also welcomed.

Comment: Are you code-generating the DTO's?

Comment: @RobertHarvey No. Manually creating them like they are POCOs.

Comment: @RobertHarvey What did you mean by __code-generating__ btw?

Comment: How exactly are you intending to generate the JSON then? How would the JSON-generating code know what members to include/exclude? The whole point of DTOs is to fulfill this role as, well, a data-transfer-object.

Comment: @JimmyBogard But does the idea I imagined above seem too farfetched in terms of AutoMapper? I just want a way to reduce overwhelming number of DTOs while not loosing advantages of AutoMapper. But then again this was a conceptual question to begin with. Your input is really appreciated.

Comment: I'm just not sure what code you would write if you didn't have AutoMapper, that's all. Our JSON is specific for individual requests, so trying to consolidate our DTOs is a fruitless exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [NewtonSoft's Json serializer](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html) and mark the properties of your Entity classes that you don't want mapped with [JsonIgnore]. No more need for DTO's, dynamic or otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. That takes care of the `Ignore()` part of AutoMapper but what about `MapFrom()` ? Those are the 2 I am having to use most.

Comment: Use the JsonPropertyAttribute and its PropertyName.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to continue using Automapper and doing this. However you could use Anonymous Types and make the WebApi methods return IHttpActionResult.

```
public CustomerDTO GetCustomer(int Id)
{
   var customer = db.Customer.Find(id));
   return new CustomerDTO{ Name = customer.CustomerName, OtherProperty = "others" };
}
```

Would become

```
public IHttpActionResult GetCustomer(int Id)
{
   var customer = db.Customer.Find(id));
   return Ok(new { Name = customer.CustomerName, OtherProperty = "others" });
}
```

The JSON or XML serializers in the WebApi would take care of creating the correct serialization and your client should receive the same output.

Output for the above would be something similar to below.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 47
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?SjpcQ29kZVxTb3VyY2VcVmFuZ3VhcmRcVk5HIEFQSVxQT0NzXFBhZ2luZ1BPQ1xNZW1iZXJz?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 08 Sep 2014 21:20:57 GMT

{"Name":"John Robers","OtherProperty":"others"}
```

There are several good articles on the web about the new IHttpActionResult here is one I found useful. It also outlines a few other new WebApi 2 features.

http://bitoftech.net/2014/03/05/new-asp-net-web-api-2-ihttpactionresult-cors-tutorial/

Comment: Its the same thing has projection and I have to repeat the same code everywhere applicable.